# How to change root url in PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, url

I need to change root url of application at start to load my.com domain. How to do this? 
Change this line below is have no effect in config.xml

```
<content src="index.html"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So is your app just a wrapper for loading a mobile site? You could use the inappbrowser plugin and load the url like so in your index.js:

```
cordova.InAppBrowser.open('my.com', '_self', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: Yes. It is good solution but, I want to redirect it very quickly. In your case I need to wait until the device is ready(the app is ready). In ideal I want to open URL immediately. Do i can do it samehow?

Comment: You could try a document ready and do a window.location.href, although you may need to add the url into your cross domain policy.

Comment: --although you may need to add the url into your cross domain policy. Where is cross domain police in PhoneGap could you tell my?

Comment: In your html at the top you will have something like

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

Comment: or in your config.xml you can have <access origin="my.com"/>